# How to ensure the first work week start with 1 in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

any idea on how to ensure the first week of the year is start with 01 not 00?

today is the first week of the year, but following code return me **00** but my desired answer is **01**, so can you share your ideas with me?

```
a = dt.datetime.now()
currentWW = a.strftime('%Y%U')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as the following:

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2018, 1, 1).isocalendar()[1]
```

Output:

```
1
```

Or if you want to proceed with `pandas`, it has `dt.week`, as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2015-1-1', '2015-12-31')})
df['Period'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W-THU')
df['Week_Number'] = df['Period'].dt.week
df.head()
```

This should produce the following output:

```
Date         Period                           Week_Number
0 2015-01-01 2014-12-26/2015-01-01            1
1 2015-01-02 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
2 2015-01-03 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
3 2015-01-04 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
4 2015-01-05 2015-01-02/2015-01-08            2
```

Comment: but i get the following error     module 'datetime' has no attribute 'week'

Comment: I will add an example for illustration.